# i did this and didnt work, what i did wrong?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gotoxy.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* Perteneciente a: Danny Saldaña, Bryan Avila
   Fecha: 21 de octubre de 2020

   ADP
Entrada: No hay entrada
Proceso: Calcular la catidad de trigo con la funcion sacar() que tiene 3 variables
Salida: Imprimir el valor de cont que es la cantidad de trigo en peso.
*/
```

Here starts the problem

```
float sacar(float a, float b,float c){
 do{

    a=a+pow(b,c);
    c++;
 } while (c<64);
 }

void main(void){
int resp,ans=2,j=0;
float cont, mover;

mover=sacar(resp,ans,j);
printf("%f \n",mover);

cont=mover*0.1;
printf("La cantidad de trigo es: %f", cont);

}
```

i dont know what i did wrong i need to know what i did wrong if someone can figure it out pls tell me

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What *did* it do?

Comment: `float sacar()` isn't returning any value - the compiler should notify you about that. It is needed by `mover=sacar(resp,ans,j);`

Comment: Is this borland-c or turbo-c?

Comment: Please don't post such question on SO as it is not really a question. The site would be useless if all questions had titles like 'It doesn't work'. Minimal politeness would also be to use the common exchange language of SO: English. It would help to know what your program is supposed to do (even using google translate would be better). Looks like the old problem of chessboard where wheat is doubled on each chessboard square. But we shouldn't have to guess. You should tell what you see and what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Many things are wrong in that code.

The purpose of the function showed seems to be computing the amount of wheat from the story about invention of chess.

As the story goes, when chess was presented to the king, he offered the inventor any reward he wanted. The inventor modestly asked that a single grain of wheat be placed on the first square of the chessboard, two grains on the second square, four grains on the third, and so on. Doubling each time.

The sacar function seems to be computing the total amount of wheat.

The first thing that is wrong is that the function is supposed to have no input ("No Hay Entrada") but the function signature takes three input variables. More than that: one of the three variables (variable 'a') has the goal of storing the result... but is used uninitialized and works as an offset to the answer.

As another answer spotted a second problem is that the function never returns the answer.

A third (or fourth) trouble is that the variable used to store the result overflows, which means the result is not accurate at all but a mere order of magnitude. That may or may not be the expected behavior. What is fun is that because of the way powers of two are working the final result is merely offset by one. Another way to get the result would actually have been to identify the rule as a geometric suite, whose final result can be computed directly.

However I would propose the alternative answer below only using integer values (I left out the final multiplication by 0.1f whose purpose is unclear to me).

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long sacar()
{
    unsigned long a = 1;
    unsigned long result = 1;
    for (unsigned c = 0; c < 64 ; c++){
        a = a + a;
        result = result + a;
    }
     return result;
 }

int main(void)
{
    printf("%lu \n", sacar());
}
```

And please, avoid posting such questions on SO, the site is not intended for homework or trivial debugging without actual question. If I were you I would even delete my question, as I wouldn't like anybody to see it in ten years and make fun of me when I was a young programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be returning the value of 'a' from the function 'sacar'

```
 do{

    a=a+pow(b,c);
    c++;
 } while (c<64);
   return a;
 }


void main(void){
int resp,ans=2,j=0;
float cont, mover;

mover=sacar(resp,ans,j);
printf("%f \n",mover);

cont=mover*0.1;
printf("La cantidad de trigo es: %f", cont);

}
```